# Asignar a un elemento <option> de un select la regla overflow-x

Tags: javascript, css, html5

Es sencillo, llevo horas intentando ajustar las etiquetas option de un select al tamaño de este, sin que se expandan mas alla del ancho que le tengo asignado al select. De tal manera que si el subelemento es mas grande que el tamaño asignado al select, aparezca un scroll en la etiqueta option.

Comment: Agrega código para que sea mas fácil ayudarte

Comment: Agrega tú codigo por favor, no esperes que hagamos tú tarea por ti.

Answer (score 1):

No se puede con un `<select>` nativo: los elementos `<option>` sólo aceptan cambios de estilo referentes al color del texto y a su fondo, el resto de personalizaciones serán ignoradas. La solución sería crear tu propio elemento *dropdown* con un input y (por ejemplo) con una `<li>` y `<ul>` que simulen los elementos `<option>`:

```js
$("ul").on("click", ".init", function() {
    $(this).closest("ul").children('li:not(.init)').toggle();
});

var allOptions = $("ul").children('li:not(.init)');
$("ul").on("click", "li:not(.init)", function() {
    allOptions.removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    $("ul").children('.init').html($(this).html());
    allOptions.toggle();
});
```

```css
select {
  width: 100px;
 color: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: red;
}

option {
  width: 100px;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: red;
}

ul { 
    height: 30px;
    width: 150px;
    border: 1px #000 solid;
    border-radius: 10px;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
ul li { padding: 5px 5px; z-index: 2; overflow-x: auto; white-space: nowrap;}
ul li:not(.init) { float: left; width: 130px; display: none; background: #ddd; }
ul li:not(.init):hover, ul li.selected:not(.init) { background: #09f; }
li.init { cursor: pointer; }

a#submit { z-index: 1; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="select">
  <option value="value1">Value 1</option> 
  <option value="value2" selected>Value 2</option>
  <option value="value3">Value 3 con un texto muy largo</option>
</select>

<ul class="list-unstyled">
    <li class="init">[SELECT]</li>
    <li data-value="value 1">Option 1 con un texto largo que produce overflow</li>
    <li data-value="value 2">Option 2</li>
    <li data-value="value 3">Option 3</li>
</ul>
```

Ejemplo con lista obtenido de [aquí](https://codepen.io/webrajendra/pen/VvjgYY)